# Can someone explain responsive functionality over responsive design?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I'm only just getting my head around how to build a responsive design site and in addition to a changing layout, I've also been tasked with functionality which should be responsive at various sizes. For example, on desktop, a link might not exist on a particular element, but then at mobile size, it should not only exist but it should also do something it didn't do at larger sizes.

I can understand using media queries to change the size or position of any particular element in CSS, but how does one go about changing functionality (i.e. JS & HTML) at various breakpoints?

(I'm not sure if the term exists or not, but for lack of a better name I'm going to call it responsive functionality.)

Comment: The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close) states that “I would like others to explain ______ to me” questions are discouraged. Can you try rephrasing as a technical or implementation problem?

Answer (score 1):

You're describing the difference between **responsive** design and **adaptive** design.

- **Responsive** layouts respond to different screen sizes (using flexible
  grids and media queries). They will often hide content or apply
  different CSS rules on smaller screens.
- **Adaptive** layouts adapt to different screen sizes and/or devices by taking a premeditated approach and **optimizing the content that is served to the user**.

For example, a responsive design might simply hide a sidebar on smaller resolutions while an adaptive design might show content specific to mobile devices (because the website knows the user is on a phone).

There are some good [blog posts](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/webmaster/what-is-the-difference-between-responsive-vs-adaptive-web-design/2540) on the topic:

> The biggest similarity between the two methods is that they both allow
>   websites to be viewed in mobile devices and various screen sizes,
>   ultimately providing visitors with a better mobile user experience.
>   Where the two methods differ is in their delivery of the
>   responsive/adaptive structures: RWD relying on flexible and fluid
>   grids, and AWD relying on predefined screen sizes. One of the main
>   distinctions between the two is that RWD might take more code and
>   implementation strategies with the fluid grids, CSS, and flexible
>   foundations, while AWD has a streamlined, layered approach, which
>   utilizes scripting to assist with adapting to various devices and
>   screen sizes.

Comment: I had always thought adaptive meant the page might change after initial load. Like with lazy loading, or ajax.

Comment: Definitely -- that is one way (of many) to implement adaptive design.

Answer (score 0):

Responsive functionality could be achieved a couple different ways:

1. You could use media queries to hide and show different segments of HTML that have different behaviors tied to them.
2. You can trigger your behavior with javascript where the javascript in the event handler examines the size/platform and decides what behavior to call.
3. You could dynamically generate different portions of HTML and their corresponding event handlers with javascript based on the size.